# Unable to override OnAfterRenderAsync in client side blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

In my Blazor client-side app, I am trying to override `OnAfterRenderAsync` using

```
@code {
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync()
    {

    }
}
```

I get an error

> no suitable methods to override!?

On the other hand this override works just fine:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{

}
```

Any clues what is wrong here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Quoting [ASP.NET Core and Blazor updates in .NET Core 3.0 Preview 9](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-and-blazor-updates-in-net-core-3-0-preview-9/)'s **Upgrade an existing project**:

> - Replace `OnAfterRender()` and `OnAfterRenderAsync()` implementations with `OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)` or `OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)`.

Since NET Core 3.0 Preview 9 `OnAfterRender` receives a boolean parameter to let method know if this is the first render. Very useful to avoid controlling it by yourself:

[image: Git hub code upgrading to preview 9]

*Sample about how to replace old code to new one, red old code, green new one.*

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
@code {
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {

    }
}
```

Note that both OnAfterRenderAsync and OnAfterRender has a boolen parameter you may call firstRender

```
 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {

    }
```

Indeed, that should work with no issues as this is the correct method signature of OnInitializedAsync